# Using Ajax and PHP in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, database, wordpress

Hi guys i am new to wordpress and ajax , i use this code for checking an input value before submitting the form :

```
$j("#ninja_forms_field_75").focusout(function(){
    var content = document.getElementById("ninja_forms_field_75").value;
       $j.ajax({
            url     : 'check.php',
            data    : {'mid':content},
            type    : 'POST',
            success : function(resp){
                if(resp == '1'){
                    //success message or whatever
            },
            error   : function(resp){
                alert("some error occured !");
            }
       }); 
    });
```

problem is i dont know where shall i put that php file to work with database...
please help me!!!

pardon my english...

Comment: [Read this to get startet](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your js file write your code above:

**javascript.js**

```
$j("#ninja_forms_field_75").focusout(function() {
  var content = document.getElementById("ninja_forms_field_75").value,
        my_data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'mid': content
      };
  $j.ajax({
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: my_data,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(resp) {
        if (resp == '1') {
          //success message or whatever
        },
        error: function(resp) {
          alert("some error occured !");
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Then the php part begins, I prefer to store it inside the functions.php if it's just one ajax request. If it is more than one create a file like ajax-handler.php and include it inside your functions.php

**functions.php**

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
  include_once( 'ajax-handler.php' );
}
```

**ajax-handler.php**

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_custom_ajax_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_custom_ajax_action' );
function my_custom_ajax_action() {
    $result = 'Hello';

    wp_send_json( $result );
}
```

Comment: and how should i link to functions.php? i mean in the url section of the Ajax

Comment: Ahh, I missed something. Look up I've edited it.

You must call to the `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` file, so therefore in the backend there is automatically assigned the variable `ajaxurl` with its url. If you use this for frontend you must assign this variable manually with [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

You link to your function with the `action` parameter inside your javascript and inside the php you will hook into this action with the `add_action` function. Therefore the js param and the action hook must have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in the functions.php, I have made a form by steps and I do it on functions.php in yout theme directory.

Comment: that's not my answer, i do not need to know how i can create forms... i need to know where should i put my php file to work with database
btw thanks for the answer